# Почему счетчик циклов выдает значение на 1 больше?

Tags: java

Ребята, даже не знаю как сформулировать вопрос. Сформулировал как есть, так что лучше гляньте простейший код. Неделю назад начал читать учебник по основам Java и решил по нему задачу:

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class Registr1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int izm=0;
        for (;;) {
            char symbol, ignore;
            do {
                System.out.print ("Введите букву для изменения ее регистра: ");
                symbol = (char) System.in.read();
                do {
                    ignore = (char) System.in.read();
                } while(ignore != '\n');
            } while(symbol != '.' & symbol < 'A' | symbol > 'z');
            if(symbol >= 'A'&&symbol <= 'Z') 
                System.out.println ("Результат: " + (symbol+=32) + "\n");
            else if(symbol >= 'a'&&symbol <= 'z') 
                System.out.println ("Результат: " + (symbol-=32) + "\n");
            if(symbol >= 'A' | symbol <= 'z') izm++;
            if(symbol == '.') break;
        }
        System.out.print("Количество измененных символов: " + (izm) + "\n");
    }
}
```

В ней есть счетчик, который выдает значение на 1 больше, чем (я полагаю) следовало бы. Мне так и пришлось изменять последнюю строку на:

```
System.out.print("Количество измененных символов: " + (--izm) + "\n");
```

Кто может объяснить чего я не понимаю ?

Comment: Вы осознанно используете битовые операции в логических выражениях?

Comment: @iksuy Видимо, нет. Он же написал, что только начал изучать основы по учебнику. Но проблема не в этом, хотя рано или поздно он столкнется и с описанной Вами.

Comment: "битовые операции в логических выражениях" это для меня как на другом языке что то прочитать. Ну для недельного то опыта программирования, надеюсь, мой код сойдет ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что условие

```
if(symbol >= 'A' | symbol <= 'z') izm++;
```

составлено неверно.

Если целью было учесть только символы между `A` и `z`, то условие должно выглядеть следующим образом:

```
if(symbol >= 'A' && symbol <= 'z') izm++;
```

В Вашем же условии даже тот же символ `.` попадает под него. И, соответственно, еще до выхода из цикла `.` подсчитывается. Почему попадает под условие? Потому что если записать по-русски, то оно будет выглядеть примерно так:

> Если символ больше либо равен 'A' (число 65) **ИЛИ** символ меньше
>   либо равен 'z' (число 122), тогда добавляем единицу.

Но символ `.` (число 46) меньше `z` (число 122).

Comment: Благодарю ! Все стало на свои места

Comment: @LS15 Если ответ верный и помог Вам, то отметьте его зеленой галочкой (под нижней стрелкой слева).

Comment: @LS15 И еще, обратите внимание на то, что указал в комментарии под Вашим вопросом  iksuy - не используйте битовые операции вместо логических. Для битовых операций используется единичный оператор,а для логических - двойной. Т.е. если бы все-таки Вам понадобилось написать в сравнении `ИЛИ` (именно в сравнении),то необходимо было бы написать `||` (два раза),  а не как у Вас `|` (один раз). Обратите внимание,что я писал в условии именно два амперсанда `&&`. Так правильно. Единичное написание - это операция над битами в числах. И то,что сейчас это у Вас *'прокатило'* не значит,что так будет всегда.

Comment: Ничего себе ! Ну я пока между & и && разницу видел только в том, что во втором случае код, который будет стоять справа, не будет проверяться, если код слева не соответствует. Надеюсь разберусь потихоньку в том что и вы сейчас написали.

Comment: @LS15 вы все правильно видели([jls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2)). Да, одиночные `|` и `&` можно использовать для битовых операций на целых числах, но для булевых операндов они ведут себя так, как вы описали. Поскольку разницы между `&` и `&&` нет, если правый операнд не функция выполняющая какие-то побочные действия, то обычно используют `&&` и `||`.

Comment: Ну плюс типовая проверка `if ( string != null & !string.isEmpty() )` вылетит с NPE, если `string == null` из-за вычисления правой части, а при использовании `&&` все будет нормально.

Comment: Благодарю за внимание ! Продолжаю изучать дальше в меру своих возможностей